# AngularJS Route Cancelling -- why do I need to use $rootScope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

I've got a form where I want to prevent the user from navigating away without saving their data back to the server. I borrowed code from [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/11/07/cancelling-route-navigation-in-angularjs-controllers.aspx) that lets me add a listener to the `$locationChangeStart`event. I put the following code in the controller for my form, and lo and behold, nothing happened.

```
    var cancelRouteListener = $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', checkForUnsavedData);

    function checkForUnsavedData (event, newURL) {
        if (!$scope.form.$dirty) {
            return;
        }

        var proceed = $window.confirm('The page has unsaved changes. Do you want to continue?');

        if (proceed) {
            cancelRouteListener();
            $location.path(newURL);
        }

        event.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
```

I could see the code reaching the call to `$location.path()`, but the page navigation didn't change. I then, out of desperation, tried wrapping that line of the code in a call to `$rootScope.$apply()`:

```
$rootScope.$apply(function () {
    $location.path(newURL);
}
```

Lo and behold, that worked. I've got a few questions:

1. Why did I need to use the `.$apply()` function? I'd have thought the code would run in the context of $rootScope.
2. Do I really need to attach this to `$rootScope`? I only need this listener when the form's route is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't you mean `$apply()`? Second, why would you use `$rootScope` to kick off a digest cycle instead of `$scope` within the controller. Third, I don't think you're using the correct logic to achieve the desired functionality. the event `$locationChangeStart` signals the start of a location change within the Angular Application. `$window.confirm()` will halt that navigation temporarily while calling `event.preventDefault()` will stop the navigation all together. Therefore, you should wait for confirmation from `$window.confirm()`. If the use clicks cancel, `proceed` will be false. If `proceed` is false, call `event.preventDefault()`, otherwise, do nothing. There is absolutely no need for you to call `$location.path()` when the application is already in the process of navigating to that page.

I've created a Plunk of the scenario here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/qfRVDtIlKqQ1p0pZ4oZ1?p=preview

Comment: First, yes, I meant `$apply()`. Second, I did that just because it was the first option I came across--I'm posting here *because I don't think I need to do that and I want to understand why*. Third, I see what you're saying with the logic, because what I'm doing is redundant. However, that's not really an answer I was looking for.

Comment: Alright. The `$rootScope.$apply()` is not necessary at all, and in fact, it shouldn't even be possible. If you're executing this logic within a controller, you should be calling `$scope.$on` instead of `$rootScope.$on`, because the `$locationChangeStart` is a broadcast event and it bubbles downward to all child scopes. That'll save you a dependency injection. You shouldn't be allowed to do this because the event listener will always be called within a digest cycle. Calling `$apply()` should blow the application up. How is your controller defined?

Comment: My controller is defined using the `.controller()` method on my module object--it's not on the global namespace, if that's what you meant. I think I understand what you're saying--using `$apply()` on `$rootScope` could cause plenty of problems. I've refactored the code to use the controller's child scope. It sounds like I was trying to follow a very sloppily coded example, so I'll chalk it up to bad practice and do it the way you've suggested from now on. Thanks!